# Python nmap port scan

Tags: python, port, nmap

I have a question for Python nmap.

I want to detect whether a port is open or closed in the IP range I entered.

When I enter the subnet mask as 24,25,26, all open ports appear as "filtered". but when I enter 27 and above, these ports appear open.

what could be the reason for this?

[image]

I need to see open ports on all IPs within 24 subnet masks. But when I enter 24 mask, all ports appear as "filtered"

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Answer (score 0):

filetered means the its being mainatined, be careful when scanning others and it shows up as filtered

Comment: Why isnt this a comment?

Comment: this is inappropriate as a answer , this should be a comment

Comment: i am new man why mad